# Unable to remove bottom border of TextInput in react native

Tags: react-native

> I am new to React Native, I am unable to hide the border of TextInput.
> Version: 0.55
> I am giving my screen.

I want this:-
[image]

And I ended up with this:-
[image]

The corresponding code for this screen is:-

JSX:-

```
<View style={styles.emailContainer}>
  <View style={styles.commonInput}>
    <TextInput style={{ paddingLeft: 15, }} placeholder="Email" />
  </View>
  <View style={styles.emailIcon}>
    <Image
      style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }}
      source={require('../../assets/images/envelope.png')}
    />
  </View>
</View>
```

Styling Code:-

```
emailContainer: {
  flexDirection: "row",
  backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  height: 40,
  marginTop: 25,
  marginRight: 10,
  marginLeft: 10,       
  borderRadius: 15,
  backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
},
emailIcon: {
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignContent: 'center',
  justifyContent:'center'
},
commonInput: {
  width: '90%'
}
```

How can I remove the bottom border from textInput?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the `underlineColorAndroid` prop of TextInput to `transparent` or the color which is the background color of the input field.

The code should look like:

```
<TextInput underlineColorAndroid ='transparent' style={{ paddingLeft: 15, }} placeholder="Email" />
```